# Use Jquery Datepicker in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am working with AngularJS. I am using jquery datepicker to enter dates.

If I manually enter date then it works but when I use datepicker it always shows ng-invalid.

jQuery:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.modal-content').valida();
                var logic = function (currentDateTime) {
                };
                $('.myCalendar').datepicker({
                    //showOn: "both",
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    //maxDate: new Date(),
                    yearRange: '1960:2099'
                });
           });
```

View:-

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control myCalendar" ng-model="employeeDOB" data-modal="modal" ng-required="true" datepicker />
```

Model:-

```
   public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

Angular Module:-

```
  var app = angular.module("myApp", ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

I also tried with change in module by adding but did not work for me.

```
app.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function () {
                element.datepicker({
                    //showOn: "both",
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    //maxDate: new Date(),
                    yearRange: '1960:2099',
                    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Of course. Angular has no idea about changes in input value. Wrap datepicker into directive.

Comment: I used the above function in module.js but its not working.

Comment: Directive looks okay (just remove `$(function {})` wrapper). It should work.

Comment: Now, I am getting this "Error: element.datepicker is not a function
.link@http://localhost:54937/Content/Module.js:9:17"

Comment: Include jQuery before angular.

Comment: thanks @dfsq its working

Comment: still works on keyboard keypress only (m using jquery validate plugin with this)

Comment: Create a demo of the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115093/discussion-between-sunil-chaudhry-and-dfsq).